# SELECT timestamp MATCH DAY 25 or 26

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I am trying to get all timestamps from the Database, that match the day of the month that are specifyed. All i have is the day numbers(*25, 26, 27 ect.*) and not a full date strings(*25/12/2018, 26/12/2018 ect.*)

**Is there a way to do:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp MATCH DAY 25
```

**Or do I need this:**

```
$day = '25';
$month = date('M');
$year = date('Y');

$timestamp = strtotime($day . '-' . $month . '-' . $year);

SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp=$timestamp
```

It will always be the current month and year, only the day changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `DAYOFMONTH()` function would do this for you

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DAYOFMONTH(timestamp) = $day
```

And if you have more than one day to look for

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DAYOFMONTH(timestamp) IN (25,26,27);
```

Comment: gr8 sir, I didn't know about the `DAYOFMONTH()` function :)

Comment: *"You can leave your hat on..."*

Comment: :) @FunkFortyNiner